# A periodic Sturm-Liouville problem: Eigenvalues of the Laplacian in One Dimension

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm following Pinchover and Rubinstein's "Introduction to Partial Differential Equations" and am trying to make sense of their analysis of the following periodic Sturm-Liouville problem.

\begin{align*}
\frac{d^{2}v}{dx^{2}}+\lambda v & =  0, & & &x\in\left(0,L\right),\\
v\left(0\right)&=v\left(L\right),&  v'\left(0\right)&=v'\left(L\right).
\end{align*}

The authors note that here we have periodic boundary conditions, which suggests
that we can extend our eigenfunctions to an $L$-periodic function
on $\mathbb{R}$, which is twice differentiable except possibly at
the points $kL,k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Assuming $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$,
we consider three cases: $\lambda <0, \lambda = 0$ and $\lambda > 0$.

I'm trying to make sense out of the first of these. I understand that for $\lambda < 0$, we have $v\left(x\right)=\alpha\cosh\left(\sqrt{-\lambda}x\right)+\beta\sinh\left(\sqrt{-\lambda}x\right)$. The authors note that,

*"In this case any non-trivial solution of the corresponding ODE is an unbounded function on $\mathbb R$. In particular, there is no periodic nontrivial solution for this equation."*

Why should this necessarily be?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is simply just better to do simple math rather than use some additional "physical" arguments. Here, assume that $\lambda<0$ then you get your solution
$$
A\cosh \mu x+ B\sinh \mu x,
$$
where $\mu=\sqrt{-\lambda}$. Use the boundary conditions:
$$
A=A\cosh \mu L+B\sinh \mu L,\\
\mu B=\mu A\sinh\mu L+\mu B\cosh \mu L,
$$
or
$$
1=\cosh \mu L+\sinh \mu L,
$$
which is actually
$$
1=\exp(\mu L)\implies \mu=0,
$$
which contradicts the assumption that $\mu>0$. This means that there are no nontrivial solutions to the Sturm-Liuoville problem with periodic boundary conditions for negative $\lambda$s.

To be fully rigorous, you should also consider case $\lambda\in\mathbb C$, which is also, however, does not yield any nontrivial solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write your solution is $v(x)=Ce^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x}+De^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$. If either $C$ or $D$ is non zero then $|v(x)|$ blows up as $x\to +\infty$ or $x\to -\infty$, respectively. The fact that periodic solutions don't become unbounded follows from the fact that we're assuming that it is continuous on its compact period $[0,L]$.

Comment: I understand that periodic solutions don't become unbounded; however, I don't understand why there is no periodic nontrivial solution. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure. Do you agree with the first two lines of what I wrote? If so, maybe this will clarify another possible issue you may be concerned about: suppose $v_1(x)$ solves your ODE on the interval $[0,L]$ and $v_2(x)$ solves the ODE on the interval $[L,2L]$ so that $v_1(L)=v_2(L)$ and $v'_1(L)=v_2'(L)$. You agree that once $v_1$ is specified, $v_2$ is also completely specified too, right? This means that $v(x)=C e^{\sqrt{-\lambda} x}+De^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}$ are the only solutions on $\mathbb{R}$ (that is, we can't choose different $C$ and $D$ for each interval $[kL,(k+1)L]$).